# Connect to a password protected FTP through PROXY in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, ftp

I'm trying to upload to my server *(on Heroku)* a file stored in a **password protected FTP**.

The problem is that this FTP also dont contain my **production IP address** on his whitelist (and **i cant** add it..) so i should use a proxy to connect my rails app this FTP.

I tried this code :

```
proxy_uri = URI(ENV['QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL'] || 'http://login:password@myproxy.com:9293')

Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port,"login","password").start('ftp://login:password@ftp.website.com') do |http|
  http.get('/path/to/myfile.gz').body
end
```

But my `http.get` returns me `lookup ftp: no such host`.

I also got this code for FTP download, but i dont know **how to make it works with a proxy** :

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp.myftp.com', 'login', 'password')
ftp.chdir('path/to')
ftp.getbinaryfile('myfile.gz', 'public/myfile.gz', 1024)
ftp.close
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise that you asked this question over 6 months ago, but I recently had a similar issue and found that this (unanswered) question is the top [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/?q=ruby+ftp+through+http+proxy) result, so I thought I would share my findings.

mudasobwa's comment below your original post has a link to the net/ftp documentation which explains how to use a SOCKS proxy...

Although you don't mention a specific requirement for a HTTP proxy in your original post, it seems obvious to me that is what you were trying to use.  As I'm sure you're aware, this makes the SOCKS documentation totally irrelevant.

The following code has been tested on `ruby-1.8.7-p357` using an HTTP proxy that does **not** require authentication:

```
file = File.open('myfile.gz', 'w')
http = Net::HTTP.start('myproxy.com', '9293')
resp, data = http.get('ftp://login:password@ftp.website.com')
file.write(data) if resp.code == "200"
file.close unless file.nil?
```

[Source](http://www.justskins.com/forums/access-ftp-server-through-134492.html)

This should give you a good starting point to figure the rest out for yourself.

To get you going, I would *guess* that you could use `user:pass@myproxy.com` for basic auth, or perhaps sending a `Proxy-Authorization` header in your GET request.